# Discord.js - Detect if a message has an image or a link

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm something of a beginner to making bots and I'm semi-comfortable in the space I'm at now only poking around at Discord.js, but I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to move forward on.

I have something of a joke bot that's supposed to detect if a person's sent an image or a link, output a reply, and then delete the image (or link). (Really, I'd prefer to delete anything that isn't text, but I need the response to say exactly what kind of media it is, so I don't care if it's particularly limited...)

Here's what I have:

```
//remove instances of images
if (message.attachments.length > 0) {
    message.channel.send(`${message.author} sent an image!`);
    message.channel.send('This constitutes revelry and merriment and is strictly outlawed!')
    message.delete();
}
//remove instances of links
if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
    message.channel.send(`${message.author} sent an link!`);
    message.channel.send('This constitutes revelry and merriment and is strictly outlawed!')
    message.delete();
}
```

However, if I send an image, it simply does nothing.

Thanks in advance!

edit: I'd also like to say that the bot has other functionality that works perfectly (reacting, deleting, replying to mentions of certain words), so hopefully the only relevant code should be above.

Comment: I realized part way through that I might have a misunderstanding as to what an embed was so I changed the second part to search for common link parts using .includes(). (https://, .com, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`message#attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) is a Collection so you have to use:
`message.attachments.size`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly for the attachments!